# How to get the count of referenced entity (by views entityreference result)?

Tags: views, entities

For example, a student can register a class. The class node has a date field indicating whether the class is active for registering. The registration node has an entityreference field referencing to the class node. I get the referencing class nodes by using "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" option. This view has a filter of "current date is between the start and the end date". Now, if the count of the reference view result rows is 0, the student should be redirected from the node/add/registration page to an explanation page which tells students there is currently no active classes for registering.
On the module [entityreference_count](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_count) page, it says,

> Currently this module only works with entityreference fields
>   configured to use the "Simple (with optional filter by bundle)"
>   option. It does not work with the "Views: Filter by an entity
>   reference view" option. This may be addressed in a future release.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Reference Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_count)

> This Entity Reference Count is in-and-of itself, just another field
>   type (called "entityreference_count" in the code) that may be attached
>   to any Drupal entity. The field may be configured to select which
>   referencing entity types and fields you want to aggregate in the
>   count. The counter field is automatically re-calculated when the
>   referencing or referenced entity get inserted, updated or deleted. The
>   Entity Reference Count's numeric field value may be enabled, displayed
>   and manipulated via view modes, through the "Manage Fields" interface
>   provided by Drupal core's Field UI, and has built-in Views
>   integration.

OR

- Make sure Child has an entity reference to Parent.
- Create a new view
- In Filter Criteria, add a new Type (`= Parent`)
- In Advanced>Other, set Aggregation to YES
- In Advanced>Relationships, add a new relationship
  for "A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via
  `field_parent`" where `field_parent` is your entity reference. Call this
  "Parents"
- In Fields, add Content: Title and when prompted set its
  Aggregation type to Group results together
- In Fields, add Field:
  Parents and when prompted set its Aggregation type to COUNT
  (Distinct)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I did not express my problem clearly. Now I clarified it, would you please give me some more instructions?